# fileno, errno: What does the "no" mean? (Non native English)

Tags: c++, c, linux

I'm a **non native English** so there are idiomatic terms I don't understand.

What does the "*no*" really means in the function `fileno()` or the header`errno.h` ?

Does the "*no*" an abbreviation of "*number*"?

If yes why?

Comment: Yes, no is an abbreviation for the number. It is a common practice to use no for number and nos for numbers.

Answer (score 10):

In the [man documentation of `fileno()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fileno.3.html) this is not explicit but this is written:

> The function `fileno()` examines the argument stream and returns its integer descriptor.

So with this explanation we should say that "*no*" means *file descriptor*.

But in the [man description of `errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) there is an explicit description:

> `errno` - number of last error

So we can deduce that "*no*" really means "*number*".

Anyway Wikipedia comes to explicit the explanation of the [Numero sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numero_sign):

> The numero sign or numero symbol, № (also represented as Nº, **No**, No./no. (US English),[1](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fileno.3.html) or **No/no** (UK English); plural Nos./nos. (US English) or Nos/nos (UK English)[2](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)), is a typographic abbreviation of the word number(s) indicating ordinal numeration, especially in names and titles.

And if you still had some doubts, there is also the [Wikipedia page for errno.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errno.h) that says:

> It defines macros for reporting and retrieving error conditions using the symbol **errno (short for "error number"**).

Comment: This is also relevant:  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/459968/why-does-no-mean-number